# Web Deploy can't deselect "Use this connection string"

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2022, microsoft-web-deploy

I have a .NET 4.8 project created using Visual Studio 2022. I installed web deploy, but every time that I deselect the "Use this connection string" at runtime (update destination `web.config`) check box, it doesn't stick.

I have tried this on multiple computers. I have VS 2022 17.7.6 version. I have tried with Professional and with Community edition.  This is a C# project.

It overwrites my production connection string and settings in my `web.config` file which I would prefer that it does not.

I have tried with this project on multiple computers.

Comment: Do the computers you tested have their firewalls turned off?

Comment: I am not using remote web deploy.  I'm copying up a package from my computer to a separate computer.  The computer that I am compiling the package on has it's firewall on.

Comment: If it is not remote web deployment, you can refer to [How to prevent web.config getting overwritten using webdeploy on an update to a site](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17880665/how-to-prevent-web-config-getting-overwritten-using-webdeploy-on-an-update-to-a)